# Webpack: how to set eslint-webpack-plugin rules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, eslint

Hot to properly set options for [Eslint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-webpack-plugin) using Webpack?

This is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
   plugins: [new ESLintPlugin({
       "skipBlankLines": true,
       "ignoreComments": true
   })],
}
```

And it throws an error:

```
ERROR in Invalid Options:
- Unknown options: skipBlankLines, ignoreComments
```

I need to disable `no-undef`, set `max-len` to 120 chars and change `indent` to `tab`.

I can't find any info in documentation, also I can't apply [Eslint doc](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len) options to this plugin.

Comment: The options you are passing are invalid, they will go in your .eslintrc file. Refer here for the valid options that you can pass in the plugin. https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api#-new-eslintoptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skipBlankLines` and `ignoreComments` are not valid options for `eslint-webpack-plugin`
Reference: [Documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin#options)

If you want to disable `no-undef`, set `max-len` to 120 chars and change `indent` to `tab`

Add this to your `.eslintrc` file in the rules section.

```
"rules": {
    "no-undef": "off",
    "max-len": ["error", { "code": 120 }],
    "indent": ["error", "tab"]
    ....
}
```